# Creating a re-usable return function but having some problems

Tags: python

below I have created an emoji converter function in Python, however, it seems to be not working. Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong? (Btw I'm relatively new to coding :))

```
def emoji_convertor(message):
    words = message.split(" ")
    emojis = {
        " :) = ",
        " :( = "
    }
    output = ""
    for word in words:
        output += emojis.get(word, word) + " "
    return output


message = input("> ")
result = emoji_convertor(message)
print(result)
```

Comment: how is it not working? What is the error?

Comment: That's not how you create a dictionary.  You have created a `set`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Looks like Tim found the problem, but I just want to mention, please read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask), which has tips like how to write a good title and how to create example code for debugging help (i.e. minimize the code, provide example input, expected output, and actual output or error).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create a dictionary.

```
def emoji_convertor(message):
    words = message.split(" ")
    emojis = {
        ":)": "",
        ":(": ""
    }
    output = ""
    for word in words:
        output += emojis.get(word, word) + " "
    return output
```

Or, better:

```
def emoji_convertor(message):
    words = message.split(" ")
    emojis = {
        ":)": "",
        ":(": ""
    }
    output = ' '.join((emojis.get(word, word) for word in words))
    return output
```